# ESP 8266 web server using arduino

Tags: esp8266

I have built a system using arduino and Ethernet shield. It gets rgb values through URL and changes an rgb led's value. Today I bought an ESP 8266 12E. I want to change to wifi but I cannot find an arduino library that uses spi to connect the arduino to the ESP. I do not want to use only the ESP. Do you know any libraries to do the job or any tutorials.

Comment: *"I do not want to use only the ESP"* -- you know you can [use the Arduino tooling and all with it](http://www.esp8266.com/arduino)? Also, *"It gets rgb values through URL and changes an rgb led's value"* sounds like it's not a web server, but a client?

Comment: Yes but I want a lot of pins like an arduino mega

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ESP communicates using the UART, not SPI. It uses modem-like AT commands. Unless you write your own ESP firmware, in which case how it communicates is up to you - and so is the accompanying Arduino library.

Comment: So, the spi pins on the ESP are for master? And what libraries are there to use with serial?

Comment: Yes, the SPI pins are for use when you write your own firmware for the ESP. There are a number of libraries around for serial - google is your friend. Or you can just do it manually without a library, the protocol is simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

The following link is a great resource for learning how to use the WiFi module.  It has all the commands you are likely to need.  The guide is written with the intent that the user will use the module as a standalone device without the Arduino, but at the end of the guide the commands given are all the same.  This is the reference I use for projects like this.  [ESP8622 Quick Start Guide](http://rancidbacon.com/files/kiwicon8/ESP8266_WiFi_Module_Quick_Start_Guide_v_1.0.4.pdf)